# What the difference between markDirty() and markForCheck()

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection, angular-ivy

With new Ivy compilation and rendering pipeline we also have a few new functions for working with change detector.

I'm interested in `markDirty()`.

As far as I understand this function provides an ability to schedule change detection firing for a component in some future. Yes, I understand that it's currently unstable functionality, but it's already provided in `angular.core`.

So my question is: What is the difference between `markDirty()` and `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()`?
And what benefits are provided by this function?

Answer (score 0):

markDirty and markForCheck  are used for OnPush [ChangeDetectionStrategy]: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

This is a special mode that only marks components dirty in two cases:

1. There has been a change to an @Input property
2. `markDirty()` has been called manually by the user.